# joomla Update not working

Tags: joomla2.5

When i want to Update my Current joomla site from 2.5.9 to 3.2.0 . so i go to Extension/update
i successfully purge cache.. and then find update . so got this Error.
'Update: :Extension: Could not open http://sito.emmealfa.it/index.php?option=com_ars&view=update&task=stream&format=xml&id=2 /extension.xml'
Anyone can tell my how to Fix it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between updating an extension and Joomla itself. Currently you're trying to update an extension. What you need to do is go to:

```
Components (top menu) >> Joomla! Updates
```

or go to the following URL:

```
www.yoursite.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_joomlaupdate
```

This is where you can update Joomla